# Android animation lag

Tags: android, performance, animation

I have a fairly simple app that requires a total of about 10 animations for various objects on the screen. The animations are fairly simple - rotate, scale etc, all described in the anim/*.xml resources.

A thing that has been puzzling me is the fact that these animations are smooth on all my test devices EXCEPT for large screen/high density screens. For example, the animations are showing terrible lag on the Galaxy Note and the Galaxy S5. I am finding it very difficult to pinpoint the cause of this issue.

On the other hand, the animations are just fine on the Samsung Galaxy 10' tablet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer of your question? I too have this issue with Galaxy Note 4 devices and I can't find resources that tell about this problem or its solution. Thank you for any help.